# Why can't RHR functions be overloaded?

Tags: c++, c++11

I could see something like the following being useful:

```
class A {
public:
   const vector<int>& vals() const {
       return val;
   }

   vector<int> vals() && {
       return std::move(val);
   }
private:
    vector<int> val;
}
```

But I get a compiler error with g++:

```
error: ‘vector<int> A::vals() &&’ cannot be overloaded
```

I would think you'd be able to do the same sort of overloading that you can with `const` functions. This would be less useful for the above accessor, and more useful for operators.

Comment: There is no function `foo` in your class..?

Comment: You can't overload something with a *ref-qualifier* with something that doesn't.

Comment: @AndréCaron sorry had copied the bug from a test that I did. Fixed it.

Comment: What is an "RHR function"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is C++11 13.1/2:

> ...
>
> - Member function declarations with the same name and the same *parameter-type-list*- as well as member
>     function template declarations with the same name, the same *parameter-type-list,* and the same
>     template parameter lists cannot be overloaded if any of them, but not all, have a *ref-qualifier* (8.3.5).
>
>   [ *Example:*
>
>   ```
>   class Y {
>     void h() &;
>     void h() const &; // OK
>     void h() &&;      // OK, all declarations have a ref-qualifier
>
>     void i() &;
>     void i() const;   // ill-formed, prior declaration of i
>                       // has a ref-qualifier
>   };
>   ```
>
>   *—end example* ]

In ohter words, your example would work if you added a *ref-qualifier* to the `const` overload of `vals()`.